# .NET MAUI workload restore error Failed to run MSBuild Target _GetRequiredWorkloads

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, maui

**When I create and Build a .NET MAUI application (.NET 6), I get the following errors.
How can I solve them?
Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4.2
Is this problem related to my country's internet? (From Iran)
Is the problem with certain individual components that I have not installed?
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS4BK.png)

[Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzl8E.png)

By executing the "dotnet workload restore" command:

```
__________________________________________________
Project "S:\Projects\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj" (_GetRequiredWorkloads target(s)):

__________________________________________________
Project "S:\Projects\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj" is building "S:\Projects\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj" (_GetRequiredWorkloads target(s)):

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(1220,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\16.1.1481\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.MultiTarget.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration ";..\16.1.1481\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.MultiTarget.targets;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.547\Sdk\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk.After.targets;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.547\Sdk\Microsoft.Maui.Core.Sdk.After.targets;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.547\Sdk\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Sdk.After.targets;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk\7.0.49\Sdk\../targets/Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done building project "MauiApp1.csproj" -- FAILED.
__________________________________________________
Project "S:\Projects\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj" is building "S:\Projects\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj" (_GetRequiredWorkloads target(s)):

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(1220,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\16.1.1481\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.MultiTarget.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration ";..\16.1.1481\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.MultiTarget.targets;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.547\Sdk\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk.After.targets;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.547\Sdk\Microsoft.Maui.Core.Sdk.After.targets;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Sdk\6.0.547\Sdk\Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Sdk.After.targets;C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk\7.0.49\Sdk\../targets/Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
Done building project "MauiApp1.csproj" -- FAILED.
dotnet : Failed to restore workload for project S:\Projects\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj: Failed to run MSBuild Target _GetRequiredWorkloads.
At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet workload restore
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Failed to resto...uiredWorkloads.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

By executing the "Dotnet workload install wasm-tools" command:

```
The machine has a pending reboot. Installation will continue, but you may need to restart.
Downloading microsoft.net.sdk.maui.manifest-7.0.100.msi.x64 (7.0.52)
Installing Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Maui.Manifest-7.0.100.7.0.52-x64.msi ............. Done
Downloading microsoft.net.sdk.tvos.manifest-7.0.100.msi.x64 (16.1.1481)
Installing Microsoft.NET.Sdk.tvOS.Manifest-7.0.100.16.1.1481-x64.msi ....... Done
Downloading Microsoft.NET.Runtime.WebAssembly.Sdk.Msi.x64 (7.0.1)
Installing Microsoft.WebAssembly.Sdk.7.0.1-x64.msi ....... Done
Downloading Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.browser-wasm.Msi.x64 (7.0.1)
Installing Microsoft.Mono.browser-wasm.7.0.1-x64.msi ............ Done
Downloading Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm.Msi.x64 (7.0.1)
Installing Microsoft.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm.7.0.1-x64.msi ...... Done
Downloading Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.Msi.x64 (7.0.1)
Installing Microsoft.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.7.0.1-x64.msi ....... Done
Downloading Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk.Msi.x64 (7.0.1)
Installing Microsoft.MonoTargets.Sdk.7.0.1-x64.msi ...... Done
Downloading Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Node.win-x64.Msi.x64 (7.0.1)
Installing Microsoft.Emscripten.3.1.12.Node.win-x64.7.0.1-x64.msi ......... Done
Downloading Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Python.win-x64.Msi.x64 (7.0.1)
Installing Microsoft.Emscripten.3.1.12.Python.win-x64.7.0.1-x64.msi ...................... Done
Downloading Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Cache.win-x64.Msi.x64 (7.0.1)
Installing Microsoft.Emscripten.3.1.12.Cache.win-x64.7.0.1-x64.msi ....................... Done
Downloading Microsoft.NET.Runtime.Emscripten.3.1.12.Sdk.win-x64.Msi.x64 (7.0.1)
Workload installation failed. Rolling back installed packs...
Removing Microsoft.Emscripten.3.1.12.Cache.win-x64.7.0.1-x64.msi ............................... Done
Removing Microsoft.Emscripten.3.1.12.Python.win-x64.7.0.1-x64.msi ............................ Done
Removing Microsoft.Emscripten.3.1.12.Node.win-x64.7.0.1-x64.msi .... Done
Removing Microsoft.MonoTargets.Sdk.7.0.1-x64.msi ..... Done
Removing Microsoft.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.7.0.1-x64.msi ..... Done
Removing Microsoft.AOT.win-x64.Cross.browser-wasm.7.0.1-x64.msi ..... Done
Removing Microsoft.Mono.browser-wasm.7.0.1-x64.msi ......... Done
Removing Microsoft.WebAssembly.Sdk.7.0.1-x64.msi ..... Done
Downloading microsoft.net.sdk.tvos.manifest-7.0.100.msi.x64 (16.0.1478)
Downloading microsoft.net.sdk.maui.manifest-7.0.100.msi.x64 (7.0.49)
Dotnet : Workload installation failed: One or more errors occurred. (Downloading microsoft.net.runtime.emscripten.3.1.12.sdk.win-x64.msi.x64 version 7.0.1 failed)
At line:1 char:1
+ Dotnet workload install wasm-tools
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Workload instal...n 7.0.1 failed):String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0cOG.png)

Comment: Please show the error messages as *text* in your question instead of as screenshots.

Comment: Note that the error message gives you a specific suggestion of how to fix this: "To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore". Did you try that? If so, what happens? If not, why not?

Comment: By executing the above command, it gives the following message: Done building project "MauiApp1.csproj" -- FAILED.
Failed to restore workload for project S:\Projects\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj: Failed to run MSBuild Target _GetRequiredWorkloads. dotnet : Failed to restore workload for project S:\Projects\MauiApp1\MauiApp1\MauiApp1.csproj: Failed to run MSBuild Target _GetRequiredWorkloads. At line:1 char:1
+ dotnet workload restore
+ CategoryInfo  : NotSpecified: (Failed to resto...uiredWorkloads.:String) [], RemoteException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: Please include that crucial information in the question, along with any more details. (I'd expect to see *why* _GetRequiredWorkloads fails.) You might also want to try "dotnet workload install wasm-tools"

Comment: I have updated the question for both the above commands. I entered the result of each of them.

Comment: Well for one thing, I'd go through the pending reboot that it's warning you about, then try again. It's *possible* that there's a block somewhere, but it's odd that it would just be for one package.

Comment: Please help me to solve the problem. An image is placed at the end of the question. Look at this. Is it possible that there is a problem with my installed Visual Studio? I really don't know what to do. I am confused.

Comment: By executing the "dotnet workload install wasm-tools" command:
Result: Successfully installed workload(s) wasm-tools.
Available in the image.

Comment: Well we still don't know whether you've rebooted as advised. (And I'd personally run all the dotnet commands from a standalone command line rather than in the Package Manager console.) I'm done here though - we shouldn't have to keep prodding for more information each time. Maybe there's a problem with VS, maybe there isn't. You might want to try doing a repair. It's hard to tell just from the information here.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same errors with the "hello world", "click me" app that is the default.   It worked for weeks then suddenly it would no longer compile.  Got the same errors.

After a few weeks of looking, this finally resolved it for me:

In the Developer Command Prompt I ran:

```
dotnet workload install maui
```

(run this with `sudo` if you get not enough permissions error)

This ran for quite a while.

After it completed I exited out of visual studio, restarted, reloaded the solution, but it still failed.  I gave it time to do all the stuff it seemed to be doing.

I exited out of visual studio more time, relaunched and I am now compiling.   (I fear it will stop again at some point).

Comment: saved my day and my head and my wall near it probably. had maui already installed and was working fine for a long time until I upgraded vsm and then you get this error.